# Ionic ItemSlide - Force ion-item-options to keep open after executing a function

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, ionic3, angularfire2

My HTML code:

```
<ion-item-sliding #item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-icon ios="ios-contacts" md="md-contacts" item-start></ion-icon>
    <strong>Rückbesuche</strong>
    <strong item-end>{{ data.revisits }}</strong>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item-options side="left">
    <button ion-button color="danger" icon-only (click)="substractRevisits()"><ion-icon ios="ios-remove" md="md-remove"></ion-icon></button>
    <button ion-button color="light">{{ data.revisits }}</button>
  </ion-item-options>
  <ion-item-options side="right">
    <button ion-button icon-only (click)="addRevisits(item)" expandable><ion-icon ios="ios-add" md="md-add"></ion-icon></button>
  </ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

If user slide to left the click calls the function `addRevisits`:

```
onSelectMonth($event) {
  this.selectMonth = $event;
  this.dbAction.getDB().subscribe(data => {
    this.currentMonthDataRevisits = data[0][this.currentUserID]['statistics'][this.selectMonth]['revisits'];
  });
}


addRevisits(item: ItemSliding) {
  this.currentMonthDataRevisits++;
  this.afDatabase.object(`data/users/${this.currentUserID}/statistics/${this.selectMonth}`).update({
    revisits: this.currentMonthDataRevisits
  });
}
```

After executing the function **without** writing into database (so, just `this.currentMonthDataRevisits++;`) the `ion-item-options` keeps open. (That´s what I want!) But when the function calls the Firebase `.update` the `ion-item-options` is sliding back to default. How can I force that the slide keeps open?

The user must be able to count up with this button. It would be exhausting if he would have to slide again every time.

**What I already tried**

```
addRevisits(item: ItemSliding) {
  this.currentMonthDataRevisits++;
  this.afDatabase.object(`data/users/${this.currentUserID}/statistics/${this.selectMonth}`).update({
    revisits: this.currentMonthDataRevisits
  }).then(() => {
      item.moveSliding(100);
  });
}
```

But it does not work. If I try the following:

```
addRevisits(item: ItemSliding) {
  this.currentMonthDataRevisits++;
  item.moveSliding(100);
}
```

... then the 'item.moveSliding(100);' fires.... why?

PS: `event.stopPropagation();` or `event.preventDefault()` after sending the $event also don´t works...

Comment: My understanding is that the button should remain in slide position until you call `close()` or the user manually slides back...  Is it possible that a listener of that `statistics...` is causing an issue?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you put your html inside `<ion-list>` as the API suggests.

Comment: My html is inside an `ion-list` with a for-loop: `<ion-list *ngFor="let data of currentYearStatisticsData | async">` ... then my content.. and yes. the button should remain in this slide position until I call close manuelly. Exactly!

Comment: Is any of your code subscribing to that event being updated?

Comment: Yes - to get the current firebase data: `this.dbAction.getDB().subscribe(data => {
      this.currentMonthDataRevisits = data[0][this.currentUserID]['statistics'][this.selectMonth]['revisits'];
    });`

Comment: for fun try commenting that guy out and see if it works as expected.

Comment: I did. It does not work...the button still close. :/

Comment: Could you reproduce it on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)?  Otherwise it might be hard with only this much information.

Comment: That´s what I need: https://ionic-f3nvbz.stackblitz.io (The comment in the function is the write into the database. If I do thism the slide position swipes back :/ if not, the swipe position stays. very strange!